# how does median of medians work with quickselect

Tags: algorithm

From my understanding, the medians of medians algorithm calls quickselect recursively. What i'm having trouble understanding is what median of medians should return. The idea is that it returns a good pivot value, but to perform quickselect we need a pivot index not a pivot value. Is there gap in my understanding? I've looked at online resources and still dont get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is flawed.

Quickselect (and quicksort) require a pivot value, not a pivot index. The partition function *returns* a pivot index, which is where the pivot value ended up after the partition. There's no way to predict where that will be.

More accurately, the algorithms require that the pivot value *have* an index, because the pivot must be an element of the array, a point which is possibly not sufficiently emphasised in descriptions of the algorithm. The pivot is not part of either partition (although other elements with the same value may be, unless you use a three-way partition). That's important because it guarantees that the algorithm will eventually terminate, because both partitions must be strictly smaller than the original array. If the pivot value were not in the array, it would be possible for one of the partitions to be empty and the other one to be the original array, which could be an endless loop.

So the pivot must have an index, but it doesn't matter which index. Typically, partitioning algorithms start by swapping the pivot value to the beginning (or end) of the array. Some partitioning algorithms will then naturally move the pivot to the correct point as the partition proceeds; other algorithms swap the pivot into the correct point when it is known. But none of them are actually influenced by where it was to begin with.

Median-of-medians finds a pivot value guaranteed to be not too far from the middle, which is enough to guarantee linear time complexity (for quickselect). Nonetheless, it's really only of theoretical interest. Selecting the pivot at random is much faster (and a lot less code), which more than compensates for the occasional bad pivot selection.

Comment: What would the partition algorithm look like? All the partition algorithms I've looked at require you to know the location of the pivot, like for example they will choose a pivot that is at the end of the array, median of medians will give a value somewhere arbitrary in the array.

Comment: @Zypher100: a common approach is to start by swapping the pivot element with the first (or last) element in the array, making it clear that its initial position was irrelevant. Some partitioning algorithms then move the pivot naturally as the partition advances; others swap it into the correct place at the end. In summary, the pivot must *have* an index --that is, it must be an element of the array-- but the particular index it has is not important.

Comment: @Zypher100: I tried to explain that better in the answer itself. Let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: yep that makes a lot more sense now, thank you heaps for the clarification!!